# Redis keys melting and not adding up

Tags: architecture, redis, docker, google-compute-engine

I've got 3 Node/Redis/Mongo stacks that I'm sending identical write streams to each.

The architectural differences are:

```
A: all hosted locally on OSX
B: using standardized Docker images on boot2docker
C: using the same Docker images on GCE (Google Compute Engine)
```

Just focusing on Redis for a second, I get the following results under constant load (30 writes/second, each write spawns 70 OPS in Redis).

After about 60 seconds, I've got ~ 150,000 keys in Redis.
Up until that point, things mostly look okay... but after that point... everything seems to melt! Here's a snapshot of what Redis reads look like on KEY_X, which expires every 12 seconds unless it's updated (in which case, I give it another 12 seconds to live)...

```
Stack A: "full/expected" in KEY_X, # total keys = 398K
Stack B: "partial" data in KEY_X, # total keys = 483K
Stack C: KEY_X doesn't exist at all anymore, # total keys = 386K
```

I'd expect the # total keys to be the same for each stack - I'm literally streaming the exact same data to each. And I'm not sure why KEY_X melts? My best guess is that it has something to do with the expire time, and overloading Redis?

Any help or idea would be great...

Comment: Are all Redis instances configured the same (redis.conf)? If so, is maxmemory set to 0? If so, do A, B and C have identical amounts of RAM and the same architecture? Remember that keys can be evicted, depending on the configured policy, when Redis reaches maxmemory (Off topic: great choice of words in the topic)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using the default config from https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/redis/ for B and C, and the default config for OSX in A. I've got 16GB RAM on A and B (B is running via boot2Docker) and C is running on a machine with 60 GB RAM. I'm not super familiar with the .config settings - if I don't want Redis to expire anything... should I set maxmemory to 0?

Comment: Zero means unlimited, which in most cases tends to get Redis killed by the OS when running out of memory. I'd use a real value (even in development). Then, you'll need to verify that maxmemory_policy is set to 'none'. Get your settings using INFO (http://redis.io/commands/info) or CONFIG GET - change by editing the conf file or CONFIG SET and REWRITE. This setting means that once your data reaches maxmemory, you'll start getting out of memory errors from Redis until some data is deleted or expired after 12 second.